# Add opencv's site-packages paths to global site-packages python

Tags: python, macos, opencv

After installing OpenCV with homebrew on MacOs Catalina, I want to add the OpenCV's site-packages paths to global site-packages of python2.7 with:

```
echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth
```

The problem is that there's no folder python2.7 in my /usr/local/opt/opencv !
However, for python3, there is a folder python3.8 in my /usr/local/opt/opencv

How can I fix this ?

Also,I don't why I'm finding python3.8 in /usr/local/lib even if I don't have it installed in /usr/local/bin. I have only python2.7 and python3.7 in /usr/local/bin.  Should I remove python3.8 from my libs? If so, how can I do this ?

Thanks